# NSNotifcation for UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, uimenucontroller

I am trying to listen for UIMenuController Notification in iphone sdk **3.0** .

But it seems that my notification can never get called. Here is my code:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(menuControllerWillShow:) name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil];
```

and my method

```
- (void)menuControllerWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
   NSLog (@"Call here");
}
```

But it never prints out "Call here", breakpoint never gets stop as well. Does anyone know how to solve this problem.

I know the approach of setMenuItems for iphone sdk **4.0** but I am working for sdk 3.0.

My original problem is that I am trying to catch the UIMenuController event to show a toolbar of buttons like: "Do A", "Do B" for the text. If anybody knows any solution for this, I also appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, several people also had your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959774/nsnotification-for-uimenucontrollerwillshowmenunotification

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/36198-uimenucontrollerwillshowmenunotification-not-working.html

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/50605-uimenucontroller-wont-send-notification.html

The last one is interesting. This issue that you have appears to be a bug in pre-4.0. I couldn't find anything about whether there was a solution.

Comment: yeah, I see it a lot when doing google. It is my attemp (may be useless) to see if anybody in SO having a solution